# How to make a content toggle slide down/up when clicked on

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I have the following C# code which populates a label:

```
specific += "</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='hoverText tooltip' title='" + this.Server.HtmlEncode(r["MessageText"].ToString()) + "'>" + strTemp + "...</span>";

lblMessage.Text = specific;
```

There can be multiple entries of the above in a single asp.net label.

The output is something like this:

[image]

I am using the following CSS which allows me to view it in a simple popup:

```
.tooltip {
    /*display: inline;*/
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 34px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: -35%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
    width: 200px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 30px;
    content: "";
    left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999999999998;
}
```

Displays the following:

[image]

The issue with that is, the X&Y are not dynamic and sometime goes off the page.

Is there any way to add JQuery/JavaScript, which will allow the user to click on the `MessageText` and the collapsed span to expand to show the full text or collapse when clicked on again.

Here is the DIV which shows the content:

```
<div id="slideContent">
    <div style="width: 98%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 5px;">
        <div id="dvImpMsgs" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Font-Size="x-small" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideContent {
    background: #E4EEF6;
    width: 289px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    float: right;
    color: #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using 30px for bottom, you can move your tooltip upwards using "top:0" and a negative margin-top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here i made you a suggestion:**

On **`tooltip:hover`** display all text thats inside a message.
And when its not hovering only show the first line of text. 
added some styles so it looks a bit more modern.

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: LightBlue;
  
}
.container label {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-indent: 6px;
}
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-indent: 5px;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label> User1 12:12 :</label>
  <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <label>User 2 12:34 :</label>
  <span class="tooltip">Ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">Dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
  <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet trempa tri uipo reti deruf truter strifu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested in IE 10 and it works great also. Thanks. I will implement it.

Comment: What if the width isn't in pixel? I updated my question. The content isn't clipped and when hovered only makes the background darker and the font bigger.

Comment: The width can be anything, the important part is the: `white-space: nowrap; `and `text-overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: If you don't what the text to be emphasized/ changed when there is enough room for it this solution get a lot harder.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question with the update. For some reason it is not hiding the overflow with the CSS you have provided :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/dmedw66r/2/ Here this is my best effort :P 
Its a bit different from the original, but it does the same.

Comment: That will do for now. Thank you for the help :)